# Strange combination of symbols UNIX

Tags: shell, ksh

I was looking at one korn shell script examples and I saw this strange combination of symbols: `%?`
So my question is what does it mean?

Comment: Please post the context in which you see that.

Answer (score 1):

You use that to refer to [jobs](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html#Jobs):

%?abc
refers to any job of which the command line contains the character string `abc`.